# Is it possible to transfer my xbox 360 account onto ps4 if I already tranfered it from xbox 360 to xbox one?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I recently purchased an Xbox One, and transferred my Grand Theft Auto Online account onto it, from my Xbox 360. I found that Xbox One didn't work for me, so I switched to PlayStation 4.

I put a lot of time into it and, frankly, I don't have the patience to do it again. Is it possible to get that account back?

Answer (score 1):

No. GTA does not support account transferring between alternate consoles of the same generation, and the transfer is a one-off affordable.

> **Taken from [the rockstar support page for account transfers](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-):** 
>   Please note:.. ..You can only transfer a set of character and progression data from PlayStation®3 or Xbox 360 once.

You can transfer between Xbox 360 and PlayStation 4, but not Xbox One and PlayStation 4, and not from Xbox 360 to Xbox One *and* PlayStation 4.

This is because the transfer is intended to accommodate upgrading consoles. Furthermore, allowing multiple transfers could lead to some serious exploitation.